# android ndk build: global cflags (or any other params)

Tags: android, gcc, android-ndk

Is there some variable that I can set in environment, so that all ndk-builds would inherit these flags?

For example:

```
set GLOBAL_CFLAGS=-DXXXXXXX=1234
ndk-build V=1 ...
...
```

here I should see that -DXXXXXXX=1234 was passed to gcc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `APP_CFLAGS`. Be careful,  though,  because if your project relies on custom `Application.mk` to set application-specific CFLAGS, your <s>environment variable</s> *setting* will obscure this.

**Update:** note that NDK will override the environment variable (Windows or Unix); you must specify the flag on command line, e.g.

```
ndk-build APP_CFLAGS=-DXXXXXXX=1234
```

Comment: didn't work. I build like 10 libs and then include them as prebuilds into my final app. I wanted to enable `-fstack-protector-all` for all of the libs without actually adding that mess to each lib's project files

Comment: Are your libraries built with `ndk-build`?

Comment: yes. I build on windows by the way. Here's cmd line that I use: `call %NDK%/ndk-build NDK_APPLICATION_MK=Application.mk NDK_PROJECT_PATH=. NDK_DEBUG=0 APP_ABI=%APP_ABI%`

Comment: Have you got separate Application.mk for each library? Does this Application.mk **override** APP_CFLAGS? By the way, to prove the concept, if you don't specify APP_ABI on the command line, does %APP_ABI% effect the build?

Comment: Ah, ok, it works if I pass it as a cmd line param to ndk-debug. I was trying to set it as an enviroment variable, which doesn't work on windows.

Comment: @Pavel: you are right, but it's not windows-specific, see the update.